# what is meaning of assigning ./ to a shell variable in linux

Tags: linux

I'm trying to use a software package for my project on linux OS. The instruction states that the following command should be executed.

```
$ var=./
```

what does this command exactly do ? I echoed the value of $var is displays.

```
./
```

as the result. what value exactly does the variable "var" hold ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a string; in general it's literally the characters `.` and `/`.  But when treated as a Unix path `.` is a reference the current directory, and `./` is the same but with a trailing slash.  So that variable could be used anywhere a path is expected, to refer to the current directory.

For example:

```
var=./
cp /tmp/myfile $var
```

Would copy `myfile` to the current directory.

Here is a (rather ugly) site that gives an [overview of Unix paths](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/12f/notes/160_pathnames.html), along with some more official resources: [working with the file system](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/c2690.htm), [orientation in the file system](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_02.html).

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly what you say it does -- it assigns the value "./" to the variable "var"

There is nothing special about the value "./" -- it is a string like any other string -- however "./" would typically be a prefix to insert into a file name to ensure that you are looking at a file in the current directory -- while many scripts does this prefix, then it is not sufficient from a security perspective to make absolutely sure that you are not accessing files outside the current directory.

The variable "var" is just a variable which then can be used elsewhere in the script.

There is no other magic.